# Designing minimaps: the more efficient way to do it

Tags: php, performance, gd

Am am making a wap-game that will have a minimap. It is basically a 5x5 div with (a) 20x20 pixel background image(s).

I've come to a stalemate trying to figure out on how to design them, though.

Making a 100x100 pixel image for each 'location' wouldn't be a good idea, since if one of those 20x20 locations changed, I would have to update 15 100x100 images.

Two choices are left then:

- Combining the 20x20 pixel images to a big 100x100 pixel one using GD
- Giving each div in the minimap a background with the 20x20 location image.

In the second scenario a lot of HTTP requests would me made to fetch the images, in the first, server resources would be used to combine them to a big image.

Which of the options do you think would be a more efficient one? Basically I see it as a lose-lose situation, but one has to decide which loss is less painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check out CSS SPRITES?

http://spriteme.org/

Then you can generate the map with a php function that select the CSS class (with its relative background) randomly.

If you have let's say 9 different parts of map 20x20, to be combined in a 3x3 grid, you just have to create a class for each piece of map. You can generate it dinamically (replace 0px 0px with a "$x = rand(0,3)*20; $y = rand = rand(0,3)*20;" or so.

```
.map1 {
    background-image:url(/images/css_sprite.png);
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-size:20px 20px;
}
```

1 HTTP request to be called, and no server resources to be wasted in GD!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know what sprites are. But I'd still have to generate the 100x100 image for them, so I guess it's the best way to go anyway. As for not using them, some of the map divs will have another background image of the character and then some <img> tags for item icons. I could technically use z-index for it, but a lot of mobile browsers don't support it. `EDIT` though if you were suggesting having the whole world map as a sprite, think about this: most mobile phone users have 3-10 kB/s download speeds when not connected to WiFi and are charged for bandwidth, not time.

Comment: There's much about to think here! Through images optimization, a world map 300x300 px would be 20kb MAX. Even with a low-speed connection, to consume lot of bandwidth you should load lot of pages. And, another question: do you think that a person with a bandwidth based plan and a lowspeed connection would play your game? I'm not saying that it doesn't worth the effort, but think about you target and optimize the game for it!

Comment: Well, there's one Russian game that also uses minimaps (although with separate images for each div) that's actually played very actively. :) as for loading a lot of pages, usually at least a hundred is loaded in one session. I'm considering making the minimap optional or having an optional low-definition version that simply  uses CSS to color the fields accordingly.

Comment: What's the name of the Russian game you mentioned? :)

Comment: Wow, really cool! It's an interesting game concept. The thing I don't like is that you move clicking on the map, and it just reload the page. Are we sure that's the best way to do it?
P.s. If you want to, I'll really be glad to talk with you about this project. Do you have an email or something where I can reach you in private? :)

Comment: Aye, that's what i'll be changing in my project. Unfortunately, it's summer, aka the season when developers would rather just lie by the lake and the whole development is going really, really slowly. I'm afraid I'd just be wasting your time. :)

Comment: It would just be an ideas' exchange, if you want to, just contact me and I'll be happy to talk with you ;)

Comment: You can remove it now, I got it ;)